# React - Splice removing too many elements from state array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create an image gallery that has a variable number of inputs. I have successfully created an add button which will add a new element to my array that is in the state. However, when I click the button to remove an element from the array, it removes all elements except the first one. Could someone help me figure out where I'm going wrong here?

My initialization/add/remove logic in parent component:

```
const newImage = {
    fileName: 'placeholder.png',
    description: '',
}

const [galleryImages, setGalleryImages] = useState([newImage])

const addNewImage = () => {
    setGalleryImages(galleryImages.concat(newImage))
}

const removeImage = (index) => {
    setGalleryImages(galleryImages.splice(index, 1))
}
```

My image gallery component:

```
const ImageGallery = ({galleryImages, setGalleryImages, addNewImage, removeImage}) => {
    console.log('gallery images:', galleryImages)
    
    return(
        galleryImages.map((image, index) => {
            const fileId = 'image' + (index + 1) + 'File'
            const descriptionId = 'image' + (index + 1) + 'Description'
    
            return(
                <Card key={index} style={{marginTop: '10px'}}>
                    <Card.Body>
                        <div style={{position: 'absolute', top:'5px', right:'5px'}}>
                            <IconButton aria-label="remove" color="secondary" onClick={() => removeImage(index)}>
                                <CancelIcon />
                            </IconButton>

                        </div>
                        <Card.Title>Image {index+1}</Card.Title>
                        <Form.Group>
                            <Form.File id={fileId} />
            
                            <Form.Label>Image Description</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control id={descriptionId} type="text" placeholder="Image description..."/>
                        </Form.Group>
                    </Card.Body>
                    { index === (galleryImages.length - 1) &&
                        <div style={{left: '0px', right:'0px', flex: 1, display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', bottom: '-30px', position: 'absolute'}}>
                            <IconButton aria-label="add another image" onClick={() => addNewImage()}>
                                <AddCircleIcon style={{color: 'green', fontSize: 40, backgroundColor: 'white', borderRadius: '50%'}}/>
                            </IconButton>
                        </div>
                    }
                </Card>
            )
        })

    )
}
```

Comment: Splice works with two parameters. A start and and end point. what does it look like when you put ```(galleryImages.splice( 0, 1))```?

Comment: I have two parameters, index (passed back from child component) and 1. I just tried hard-coding the 0 in and I have the same result.

Comment: The return value of [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) is an array, consisting of the removed element(s). You're setting this value as your state. Consequently, your new state contains the element you wanted to remove.  The function *does* mutate the original array; whiy is something you shouldn't do to your state in React. Consider cloning the array, use ˙splice˙, then set the cloned array as your new state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splice mutates the array directly, which is generally disapproved in React.

While the recommended approach is using the filter method to remove, you can do it in this way if u want to use splice -

```
const removeImage = (index) => {
    //create a new array here with the spread operator of the original array. 
    //Without this, react won't recognize the change and the child component won't be re-rendered!
    const galleryImagesData = [...galleryImages];
    galleryImagesData.splice(index, 1)
    setGalleryImages(galleryImagesData)
}
```

Comment: changing my removeImage code to:


`const removeImage = (index) => {
        const newArray = galleryImages
        newArray.splice(index, 1)
        console.log('new array:', newArray)
        setGalleryImages(newArray)
    }`


Shows the desired effect in the console.log, but not in the react render

Comment: changing from `const newArray = galleryImages` to `const newArray = [...galleryImages]` solved it for me. Since it was returning the same array, the child component did not re-render. Creating this new array with the spread operator on the old one, React determined there was an update and re-rendered. If you'd like to update your answer to reflect this, I'll mark yours as the accepted answer.